# Debian doesn't alert low battery

Tags: bash, debian, gnome

My Debian 10 (Buster) doesn't alert low battery on the display, it only alerts 1 percent battery which is late for plugging in the charger.
I've also created a cron job to run every minute to alert if battery is less than 15 percent. but it doesn't. this is the bash file the cron runs:

```
battery_level=`acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)'`
if [ $battery_level -le 4 ]
then
    notify-send "Battery low" "Battery level is ${battery_level}%!"
    mkdir ~/testing_if_bash_runs
fi
```

the `mkdir ~/testing_if_bash_runs` runs but the `notify-send` doesn't.
any clues what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any programs that are run from a cron job are not part of your desktop session, so that they can run whether or not you are logged in.

That means they won't get the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable, which is needed by `notify-send` to access the session D-Bus, so it can send the notification.

The default value for that variable for KDE seems to be `unix:path=/run/user/<your_UID>/bus` in Debian 10, and `/run/user/<your_UID>/` is accessible by your user account only. For Gnome it seems to be different: something like `unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-0VDJayoNDs,guid=9897d6d93070adc85634b1fb5f631033` and I would guess it changes on every login.

So if the cron job is running on your account, you might do something like this:

First, create a script that will run at GUI login. Put it wherever you like, e.g. `~/bin/record-session-bus-address.sh` for example. Mark it executable (`chmod a+x ~/bin/record-session-bus-address.sh`). The contents of the script should be like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" > $HOME/.local/session_bus_address
chmod 600 $HOME/.local/session_bus_address
```

Add a file `~/.config/autostart/record-session-bus-address.desktop` with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=record-session-bus-address
GenericName=Record session bus address
Comment=Record session bus address for a cron job
Exec=~/bin/record-session-bus-address.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Then make your cron job like this:

```
battery_level=`acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)'`
if [ $battery_level -le 4 ]
then
    myUID=$(id -u)
    if [ -f $HOME/.local/session_bus_address ]
    then
        # Faramarz may be logged in
        export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(cat $HOME/.local/session_bus_address)
        # strip prefix and suffix to get the plain dbus socket name
        DBUS_SOCKET_PREFIXED=${DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS%%,guid=*}
        DBUS_SOCKET_PLAIN=${DBUS_SOCKET_PREFIXED##unix:abstract=}
    else
        # Not logged in, make sure the next test fails
        DBUS_SOCKET_PLAIN=/dev/definitely_does_not_exist
    fi
    if [ -w "$DBUS_SOCKET_PLAIN" ]
    then
        # Faramarz is definitely logged in, send a notification
        notify-send "Battery low" "Battery level is ${battery_level}%!"
    else
        # Faramarz is not logged in, do something else.
        # This example requires /etc/sudoers entry like this:
        # Faramarz ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/beep
        sudo beep -l 1000 -f 2700 -n -l 1000 -f 2000 -n -l 1000 -f 1000
    fi
fi
```

Comment: still no changes, i added the `mkdir ~/testing_if_bash_runs` to logged in case, it runs but notification doesn't.

Comment: Hmm, it might need other environment variables too, perhaps the XDG_* variables. Or perhaps the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is formed differently when using GNOME?. I use KDE so I may have missed that.

Comment: could you please edit the question? my `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` value is  `unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-0VDJayoNDs,guid=9897d6d93070adc85634b1fb5f631033`